# How to hide a menuitem if its submenu is collapsed?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]I have a menu as below:

```
 <MenuItem Margin="10" x:Name="Products" Header="Products" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <MenuItem x:Name="ProdCodes" Header="Product Codes" Click="ProdCodes_Click" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <MenuItem x:Name="Formulations" Header="Formulation" Click="Formulation_Click" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <MenuItem x:Name="ProdGroupText" Header="Group Text" Click="ProdGroupText_Click" Visibility="Collapsed" />                    
            </MenuItem>
```

At runtime, I check(in database) whether to display the submenu and display it accordingly. But there are times, where I have to hide all the submenus. In that case, I need to hide the menu(Products) as a whole. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the Visibility property of your parent-menu using a converter. Inside the converter, check if all its sub-menu items are collapsed or not. Depending on that outcome, return "Collapsed" or "Visible".

In case you have not encountered converters yet, here is a tutorial on how to create one.
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters

Comment: setting `Product.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden` leaves a "hole" where it was

Comment: set the visibility to collapsed rather than hidden

Comment: <MenuItem x:Name="Products" Header="Products" Visibility="{Binding Header, Converter={StaticResource ConvertMenu}}"> . This doesnt work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit last and if I understood it good...

If you are hot with Behaviors you can get it too... Personally I have a trigqer in style who set visibility of all roles (parents or leafs) of menuItems to collapsed when IsEnabled is false and my leafs item are linked with commands.

```
public class DisableMenuItemIfNoEnabledChildBehavior : Behavior<MenuItem>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Command = new RelayCommand(
            p => { /*nothing*/ },
            p => AssociatedObject.Items.OfType<MenuItem>()
                    .Any(mi => (mi.Command != null && mi.Command.CanExecute(mi.CommandParameter)) || (mi.Command == null && mi.IsEnabled))
            );
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Command = null;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }
}
```

And in xaml part:

```
<MenuItem Header="Parent MI"
          xmlns:b="clr-namespace:YourNsHere.Behaviors"
          xmlns:bh="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Control Template="{StaticResource chat}" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
    <bh:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:DisableMenuItemIfNoEnabledChildBehavior />
    </bh:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding MaybeCanExecute}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding}" 
              Header="Child MI 0">        
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Control />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Child MI 1"
              IsEnabled="False">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Control />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```